# Starting a Thread to open a Server on port makes the app crash

Tags: java, android, networking, server, port

I'm trying to start a server in order to receive messages on a certain port; but the app keeps crashing when i click the start server button, i think when this code is executed:

```
showMessage("Try starting server...", Color.WHITE);
this.serverThread = new Thread(new ServerThread());
this.serverThread.start();
```

Since the message "Try starting server..." is visible for a second before the app crashes.

This is main activity full code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

private ServerSocket serverSocket;
private Socket tempClientSocket;
public Thread serverThread = null;
public static final int SERVER_PORT = 3034;
private LinearLayout msgList;
private Handler handler;
private EditText edMessage;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setTitle("Server");
    msgList = findViewById(R.id.msgList);
    handler = new Handler();
    edMessage = findViewById(R.id.edMessage);

    showMessage(getIPAddress(), Color.WHITE);
}

public TextView textView(String message, int color) {
    if (null == message || message.trim().isEmpty()) {
        message = "<Empty Message>";
    }
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setTextColor(color);
    tv.setText(message + " [" + getTime() +"]");
    tv.setTextSize(20);
    tv.setPadding(0, 5, 0, 0);
    return tv;
}

public void showMessage(final String message, final int color) {
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            msgList.addView(textView(message, color));
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (view.getId() == R.id.start_server) {
        //msgList.removeAllViews();
        showMessage("Try starting server...", Color.WHITE);
        this.serverThread = new Thread(new ServerThread());
        this.serverThread.start();
    }
    if (view.getId() == R.id.send_data) {
        String msg = edMessage.getText().toString().trim();
        showMessage("Server : " + msg, Color.BLUE);
        sendMessage(msg);
    }
}

private void sendMessage(final String message) {
    try {
        if (null != tempClientSocket) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    PrintWriter out = null;
                    try {
                        out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                                new OutputStreamWriter(tempClientSocket.getOutputStream())),
                                true);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    out.println(message);
                }
            }).start();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

class ServerThread implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
        Socket socket;
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVER_PORT);
            findViewById(R.id.start_server).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            showMessage("Error Starting Server : " + e.getMessage(), Color.RED);
        }
        if (serverSocket != null) {
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                try {
                    socket = serverSocket.accept();
                    CommunicationThread commThread = new CommunicationThread(socket);
                    new Thread(commThread).start();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    showMessage("Error Communicating to Client :" + e.getMessage(), Color.RED);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

class CommunicationThread implements Runnable {

    private Socket clientSocket;

    private BufferedReader input;

    public CommunicationThread(Socket clientSocket) {
        this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
        tempClientSocket = clientSocket;
        try {
            this.input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            showMessage("Error Connecting to Client!!", Color.RED);
        }
        showMessage("Connected to Client!!", Color.GREEN);
    }

    public void run() {

        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            try {
                String read = input.readLine();
                if (null == read || "Disconnect".contentEquals(read)) {
                    Thread.interrupted();
                    read = "Client Disconnected";
                    showMessage("Client : " + read, Color.GREEN);
                    break;
                }
                showMessage("Client : " + read, Color.GREEN);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }

}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (null != serverThread) {
        sendMessage("Disconnect");
        serverThread.interrupt();
        serverThread = null;
    }
  }
}
```

Any idea about why this is happening?

Thanks.

Comment: Use Logcat to examine the stack trace associated with your crash.

Comment: `findViewById(R.id.start_server).setVisibility(View.GONE)` That influences the gui. And you cannot update the gui from a thread.

Comment: Also you cannot use showMessage() in a thread.

Comment: Removing setVisibility solved the issue. Thanks!